# Can Windows 7 burn iso images to DVD's natively?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, iso-image, burning, compact-disc

Can Windows 7 burn iso images to DVD's natively?  If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. An [episode of Windows 7 in 77 Seconds](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqOo1YyLY1o) covers this. Basically, right-click ISO file -> Burn Disc Image.

[image]

Comment: @fideli Thanks a bunch!  Great answer and cool screencasts link!

Comment: I want to add that native burner of Windows OS doesn't allow to create a bootable media.

Comment: @NamG.VU: Since the question was about burning ISOs, that's completely irrelevant. If the ISO is an image of a bootable CD, the resulting CD will be bootable.

Comment: @vezult I don't get it. What is an un-bootable Windows 7 ISO image used for?

Comment: @NamG.VU you absolutely can create bootable media, if the ISO is a bootable image.  I just did it using the Xubuntu 12.10 disc image.